# How to pass Unicode value as parameter for select command

Tags: asp.net, sql

Here is my code but it returns `-1` value. The `Name` field contains a unicode value.

```
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
  {      
      string str = string.Format("select SrNo from Jat where Name=@Name");
      SqlCommand dCmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
      try
      {               
          dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name","N" +Name);
          int i= dCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          return i;
      }
      catch
      { 
           throw; 
      }
   }
```

Comment: See this : **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548371/unicode-sql-query-w-parameter-instead-n-prefix**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no need to write down

```
dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name","N" +Name);
```

**remove "N" from this but it doesnt create nvarchar parameter**

```
dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
```

To create nvarchar type parameter than you can do this

```
dCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = Name;
```

this will create nvarchar parameter than you can add this parameter as nvarchar parameter

**one more change in code is make use of [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)**

```
int i= Convert.ToInt32( dCmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

make use of ExecuteScalar method rather than ExecuteNonQuey ....becuase non Sclar method return value of you SrNo and NonQuery return you row affected when using update and insert query

Comment: @Somnath - Check your database against the passed in name. The query requires it to be _identical_.

Comment: @Somnath - make use of ExecuteScalar method rather than ExecuteNonQuey ....becuase non Sclar method return value of you SrNo and NonQuery return you row affected when using update and insert query

Comment: thanks @PranayRana it works by using int i= Convert.ToInt32( dCmd.ExecuteScalar());

Answer (score 2):

First, the N'' is only required in TSQL for Unicode string literals.

Second, if you want to return the SELECTed `SrNr`, use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)()